# Peer 2 Peer connection in Java

Tags: java, routes, network-programming, p2p, file-sharing

I have been given a project in which I have to share files with peers without any intermediate server. I want to know how to know how many hosts are online on the network and how to connect to them. I have to roughly make Routing table for the hosts in my computer through Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to keep any track of routing. All you need is to know the endpoints addresses.

You may find out if a host is connected to the network by establishing a connection with this host.

You mentioned that there will be no intermediate server, so the NAT hole punching is out of scope of your question.

As the starting point look at `java.net.Socket` class documentation.

Comment: I can get the remote host IP address with getInetAddress() ... but don't understant how to 1st connect to the other endpoint if I don't know its address and server implementation is not allowd. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RahulKumar Could you please clarify your question a bit. It is too abstract to give you any advice

Comment: 5 computers are connected to each other over a network say Hub. File sharing is to be done between then using p2p connection without any intermediate server. I want to know how to implement it and how to connect each host to each other with their MAC address as it is done in DC++

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this is on a private network. Something that's relatively contained. Letting them find each other over the internet sounds like a nightmare.

So, given this, one model for your peers to find each other might be to select a standardised sequence of ports and an alive signal. Then when a peer searches for others, it simply goes through all the IPs on the network and makes a request on that port number. If it gets an alive signal it adds it to a table. The signalled computer would have to record the new comer as well.

You'd have to select the port sequence such that they're generally unused on the network. (Quite large) I say sequence so that there's a preference in ordering to speed up the search.

To speed up the search even more, when an alive signal is sent, it could also send it's peers table and the IPs it checked (and the ones it received in the same way). Then the new peer would only have to check new IPs on the network since old IPs with a new instance of the program would establish themselves.

Hope that helps

Comment: do we have to broadcast the peer table each time with all host?

Comment: No, not at all. You can scan the whole network if it's easier for you. It is a bit more work to make the system to send back the table, but it would probably reduce the network overhead of the overall system.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest you not to go with mac address,it will be better if you turn your dhcp off of your router (if you can include one of course........but if you only can include an hub you'll be forced i guess to use mac address).and use manual addressing for your ipv4 address,and you will be able to easily connect to the other computers.